# how to retrieve data from excel sheet in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Someone please help,
I'm trying to get a particular record that match from an Excel file to display on the web page.  The Excel file is on the host server.  Here is the code and I'm not sure where the issue at.

```
<input name="searchPhrase" type="text" /> <a href="javascript: searchExcel();" style="padding: 1px 5px; border: 1px solid black; font-variant: small-caps; background: #efefef; width: 50px; text-decoration: none; color: black; margin-left: 10px;">Search</a>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function searchExcel() {
    var searchPhrase = document.getElementById('searchPhrase').value;
    var Worksheet = 'https://19953.sites.ecatholic.com/documents/2018/3/SF2017.xls';
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application');

    Excel.Visible = false;
    var Excel_file = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Worksheet, null, true, null, null, null, true, null, null, false, false, null, null, null);

    var range = Excel_file.ActiveSheet.Range('A:A');
    var jsRangeArray = new VBArray(range.Value).toArray();

    var found = false;
    for (cells in jsRangeArray) {
        if (jsRangeArray[cells] == searchPhrase) {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Found";
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (found == false) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Not Found";
    }

    Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(true);
    Excel.Application.Quit();
    Excel = null;
}
```

Comment: [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] are not the same thing.  They are as similar to each other as car and carpet.

Comment: what are you expecting to see? any errors to share or does it fail silently?

Comment: @zbnrg it fail silently, I enter a record that exist in my Excel file and click on Search, it doing nothing.

Comment: What browser are you using? `ActiveXObjects` are only available on Microsoft browsers.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure that someone, somewhere has written a JavaSript library that parses Excel files, your approach is unlikely to work.

First, it looks like you're trying to do server-side stuff in the client.
Even if you could get that to work, it would still only work on a Windows client that has Excel installed.

Better to do this server-side.
How to do that depends largely on your server-side development environment.

Answer (score 0):

As GreyBeardedGeek mentions your approach is pretty dependent on Windows operating system. My suggestion for you is to have a look [xlsx node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) .

> Parser and writer for various spreadsheet formats. Pure-JS cleanroom
>   implementation from official specifications, related documents, and
>   test files. Emphasis on parsing and writing robustness, cross-format
>   feature compatibility with a unified JS representation, and ES3/ES5
>   browser compatibility back to IE6. ***js-xlsx***